# Can a signed long long be used as an iteratorion variable in OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp, unsigned

I am trying to test out the performance of this program, before I used to have unsigned long long because I saw this as an example, but now that I am trying to parallelize it, the counter must be signed

But I am not sure if my results are returning a counter of only 1 because the data type of counter is signed long long and not unsigned long long. Or if it has to do with OpenMP with Xeon Phi.

On an OpenMP [tutorial website](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ExampleInitializingATableInParallel), it says the following: "the iteration variable in for must be a signed integer variable type. In OpenMP 3.0, it may also be an unsigned integer variable type, a pointer type or a constant-time random access iterator type."

```
[...]
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <omp.h>

    [...]    
    size_t i, j;
    signed long long counter = 0;
    [...]
    if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
    {
        counter = 1;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for private(counter)
    for(i = 1; i < smallest; i++)
    {
        ch1 = getc(fp1); 
        ch2 = getc(fp2);

        if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    [...]
```

Complete code at http://pastebin.com/ESU1yXYT

Do I have to cast some data type in order to find the percentage? Or is it probably just an OpenMP problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration variable of your omp parallel for loop isn't `counter`, it's `i`, which has a type of size_t, not long long. Your issue is that you declare `counter` as private in the loop, which according to [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#PRIVATE) means that a new counter object is created for each thread, and all references to the original object are replaced by new ones. I'm not sure exactly what the defined behavior is for `counter` once you've exited the for loop, but it definitely isn't what you're looking for. You probably want to do something like a reduction

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:counter)
for(i = 1; i < smallest; i++)
{
    ch1 = getc(fp1); 
    ch2 = getc(fp2);

    if((ch1 ^ ch2) == 0)
    {
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3dabskb.aspx), the value of `counter` after the parallel for loop should be the same as it was prior to entering the loop, though I don't know if this is general or implementation-specific behavior.